# Unsure about an 'and' operation

Tags: python, operands

I came across a piece of code to calculate the number of binary bits needed for a decimal.

```
nbits = 1 + (decimal and floor(log2(decimal)))
```

I understand that `1+floor(log2(decimal))` returns the number of `nbits`.

However I'm not sure what the `and` statement ensures here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's taking advantage of the fact that `0` is a falsey value; it's a compact form of

```
bits = 1 + (0 if decimal == 0 else floor(log2(decimal)))
```

or even less compactly,

```
if decimal == 0:
    bits = 1  # 1 + 0
else:
    bits = 1 + floor(log2(decimal)))
```

`floor(log2(0))` is undefined, so you need to handle `decimal == 0` specially.

`x and y == y` for any truthy value of `x`, and `x and y == x` (without evaluating `y` at all) for a falsey value.

In short, it says that `bits` is at least 1 bit (`0`), but may require additional bits for non-zero values.